# Offline private NPM repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server

I read about building private NPM mirrors/repositories, but didn't quite understand.

My goal is to make a repository that currently up to date, that contains all NPM packages available at the NPM website (The free packages) that I need.
After downloading all packages I need to move it to a private network which is not connected to the internet.
And set up a repository that will accept NPM requests in that private network.

every month I will update the packages I have outside the private network, and enter it to our private network again.

I never done anything like this before, Can anyone like guide me through it
or Does anyone has a reading source that will explain step by step?

Good day !

Comment: You want to Download 200242 packages every month?

Comment: I never said I want to download 200242 packages every month. at the first step download in batches or filter what I need by tags, even if it will take a while to download most of them.  and then keep them updated in a smart way,  that something to think about for the "next step".  there is no need to make a question sound stupid.   I have a problem, which need to be solved so our work in the private network wont be hell.

Comment: You'r being immature. It isn't the situation, NPM is like a HUGE library. and I want to take books that might be useful for me that belongs to some categories.  yes, I wont use ALL of them. I just want them to be available for me when I wont be able to approach the NPM library.  Yes, I might shouldn't use the world "all" at the first post. but that's what I planned to do.    to make the script to search what is useful for me Isn't that hard to do. its mostly the setting up the NPM mirror that I don't know how to do.

Comment: @baao now who sounds silly? http://blog.runkit.com/2016/09/13/tonic-is-now-runkit-a-part-of-stripe.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be one way of doing what you want:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160310020204/https://www.clock.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository

(I've updated the link to a Wayback machine link since it was taken offline by original host.)

UPDATE: There seem to be a few ways to do this now.

For example:

1. https://codebox.sh/ - free private npm registry
2. http://blog.runkit.com/2016/09/13/tonic-is-now-runkit-a-part-of-stripe.html: "We started by buidling module-fs, a virtual filesystem capable of representing the entire state of npm at any particular microsecond. With module-fs we could make every version of the over 300,000 packages on npm available instantly. With truly immediate and frictionless access to any package, you could begin to think of npm as the global standard library, as essential to development tomorrow as built-in libraries are today."

Comment: The clock.co.uk link now 404s and codebox.sh is not free (at least not anymore).

Comment: @damd I've added a Wayback Machine link to the original content - not as nicely laid out but perfectly readable.

Comment: you can use the `verdaccio` to manage the `offline registry npm`

Comment: @AminRostami how you transfer the packages from an internet enabled workstation into the offline intranet "prison"?