# Creating a replica of NPM registry on an offline machine?

Tags: node.js, npm, server, offline

So I have a need to do some new web development on a standalone box on a standalone network. This standalone network does not have any access to internet, but there are quite a few machines on it that operate in a Windows Server environment.

I have an internet-accessible machine with which I could download node and get the packages, but I need to be able to transfer the packages en masse over to the standalone machine.

What's the best way for doing that? I've read a few docs about replicating the registry on a local machine so it caches it, but how would I take that cache and port it over via usb to this standalone network?

Are there other methods for handling this?

Previously on a different project, we established our own private npm repo using Verdaccio, and published our own npm modules to that repo. I could easily set that up and then port over tar or zip files of node modules and publish them that way. But again the question is, how do I get the bulk of node packages I need?

The main thing I need to know is how to take this locally cached npm registry and set it up on a standalone machine once all the modules are copied. I can do that all on the internet box, but how would I transfer and replicate all on the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline private NPM repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450120/offline-private-npm-repository)

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/Caspia/npm-offline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem.

I install and use the `verdaccio` and resolved my problem.

thanks to [juan picado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308341/juan-picado)

what you need is **cache** properly all dependencies in your storage folder.

see [here how to find it](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/cli#default-storage-location)

(`e.g in windows 8.1`: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache)

You should be able to see all the resolved dependencies in the cache.

then set `Environment variable` with name: `XDG_DATA_HOME` in follow path:

1. right click on MyComputer
2. click properties.
3. from left panel, click `Advance system settings`.
4. from `Advance` Tab click `Environmrnt variable ...` button.
5. in new opened from, in `system variable` group. click `new` button.
6. enter `XDG_DATA_HOME` to `Variable name` and **cache** path to `Variable value`.
7. click `Ok` button.

now, go to `config.yaml` and comment `proxy` in `packages` section. follow this:

```
packages:
  '@*/*':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    # proxy: npmjs

  '**':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    # proxy: npmjs
```

change registry config url.

```
npm config set registry http://localhost:4873/
```

finnally, restart verdaccio.

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 0):

verdaccio was not really meant for this use case, I would rather run this package on a container "npm-offline-registry". if you go with versaccio, you may encounter some difficulties setting it up for an offline network.